# How to overcome Time Limit Exceeded in Python

Tags: python, performance

I am doing this exercise [Find Pivot Index](https://leetcode.com/problems/find-pivot-index/), took me a long time to complete,
passed sample cases but received Time Limit Exceeded error in submission which is frustrating

I wonder how to calculate/estimate the constraint to avoid TLE beforehand?
I feel like this must be related to the given constraints, but I don't think I fully understand what these mean.

constraints

1 <= nums.length <= 104

-1000 <= nums[i] <= 1000

```
class Solution:
    def pivotIndex(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        cur = 0
        l = 0
        r = 1
        rightSum = 0
        leftSum = 0
        n = len(nums);
       
        while cur < n:
            rightSum=0
            leftSum=0
            r=cur+1
            while r <n:
                rightSum+=nums[r]
                r+=1;
            l=0
            while l< cur:
                leftSum+=nums[l]
                l+=1
            r+=1
            if leftSum ==rightSum:
                return cur;
            cur+=1

        return -1 ;
```

I used an intuitive approach to compare leftSum and rightSum , return the current position when they equal
[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your algorithm is that it runs in quadratic time (i.e. `O(n**2)` where `n` is the size of the input array) while it could run in linear time (i.e. `O(n)`). The point is that you recompute the sum of the right part many times. This is not efficient because you only need to compute it once. You can **store the cumulative sum** in another array not to recompute it later (and get the right sum in constant time). You can for example pre-compute it at the beginning or just iteratively when it is needed based on the previous computed sum (see [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming#Examples:_Computer_algorithms)). Note that you can compute the cumulative sum easily and efficiently with the [Numpy](https://numpy.org/) function `numpy.cumsum`.

Actually, a simpler algorithm is to compute the cumulative sum from the left to the right and in the reverse order and store them in two different arrays. Then, you can easily find the answer by iterating over the two array in lockstep from 0 to n to check if the left part is equal to the right part (excluding the current item).

Comment: There's no need to store the sums; just: - calculate total sum of array. keep running sum starting at 0, then: - for each element: if (totsum-current) == (runsum), return current; else: totsum -= current, runsum += current

Comment: Indeed, good strategy! It is `O(1)` in memory, but still require two walk ;) . A slightly better approach would be to compute the partial sum of both side at the same time in order to find the middle. To do that, the minimal partial sum have to be incremented at each iteration step. When they are equal and the gap between the two is 1 item, then the pivot is found.

Comment: Could you explain your comment further? I can't see how it would work, especially in edge cases like

[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, ..., 1000]

Comment: @Tordek could you elaborate on your solution? I've tried implementing it and I can't get it to work.

Comment: https://www.ideone.com/iq0nu7 @rangeseeker (This returns the index of the value, as requested in the problem, but that's a trivial change from the pseudocode explanation)

Comment: @Tordek To be more precise, only the side with the smallest partial sum is incremented (not both for a given iteration, a bit like the Hoare partition scheme). In this case the left sum will be increased a lot of time as long as the right sum is bigger (so about 1000 times to be greater than 1000). If there is 1000 times 1 the algorithm will end with the left and right partial sum being unequal resulting in the output -1. If there is 1001 times 1, then the sum will be equal when the main loop will be completed and the output value will be the index of the last remaining left (before 1000).

Comment: There can be negative numbers in the list; something like [1, -1001, -1000] wouldn't work with your example. Also a list like [1, -1] has 0 (or n) as result, so how does your algorithm choose which side to move? If I'm mistaken I'd appreciate a code sample.

Comment: Ha, you are right about the negative values. Good catch! I think the broken hypothesis required by this alternative algorithm was that the cumulative sequence must be a monotonic one (which is not the case with negative values).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def pivotIndex(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
    for index in range(0, len(nums)):
        if sum(nums[:index]) == sum(nums[index + 1:]):
            return index
    return -1
```

Best I could get, not very fast though.

Comment: This suffers the same problem as OP's own answer.